# Override Comparable interface for GAE property?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, objectify

I'm not sure if this is possible at all, but is there a way to override the Comparable used by a Google App Engine property when used in a query? For example, there is a property type `PhoneNumber` (basically a String) that in the docs has a method:

```
public int compareTo(PhoneNumber o)
    Specified by:
    compareTo in interface java.lang.Comparable<PhoneNumber>
```

The exact workings of how it compares I haven't been able to find. Is there a way to override that Comparable so that it compares it in a way I choose?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

No. But you can sort any collection any way you want. Since you tagged this with objectify:

```
@Entity
public class Thing {
    private static final Comparator<PhoneNumber> SPECIAL_COMPARATOR = // make one

    // ... id, etc
    SortedSet<PhoneNumber> phoneNumbers = new TreeSet<>(SPECIAL_COMPARATOR);
}
```

This won't help you if you need the phone numbers indexed in a particular way (although collection property index sorting would be very strange anyways). If you have a single indexed phone number property and you want to control index ordering, you need to create your own `PhoneNumber` that translates to a correctly-sorted String representation. You'll need to register your own `PhoneNumberTranslatorFactory` with Objectify. This is not hard; look at the source code for examples.

Comment: The idea was to try and use Google's phone number library to query for numbers that have a match above a certain threshold, as phone numbers can be given in many formats. I'm not sure sorting could help with that.

Comment: Indexes are just chunks of data in a datastore. They aren't java data and there's no java code involved. You can't change some java code in your client and expect the datastore to execute queries any differently - it has its own idea of how to compare basic types.